# DB design for combining two one to one table

Tags: database, database-design

I have a legacy application which has below tables which has 1 to 1 mapping

```
 customer (has already 40 columns)
 customer_additional_attributes(has 20 columns)
```

My question :- Would not it be better design if `customer` and `customer_additional_attributes` tables were combined as it would have saves extra join or query sometime to fetch data
from `customer_additional_attributes` ?

Is there any disadvantage of single table(like in above scenario) but large number of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data format that you have is called "vertical partitioning".  This is when rows of an entity are split across multiple tables.  In a normalized structure, this is problematic, because inserts of rows (for instance) are not necessarily atomic -- they affect two tables.

But there are good reasons for doing this.  The most obvious is when the rows are too wide.  If the columns are too wide, they simply will not fit in one table, so they are spread through multiple tables.

Similarly, if some columns are much larger -- and rarely used -- then putting them in another table can be a big win on performance.

Before combining the tables, you should recognize that the data structure is intentional.  It might simply be the result of "laziness".  The first table was created -- and then additional attributes came along so they were put into another table.  Or, it could be quite intentional, and you would want to understand why.

Note that the join between the two tables should be pretty fast, particularly if the same primary key is used for both.

Comment: `The most obvious is when the rows are too wide. If the columns are too wide, they simply will not fit in one table` Not sure what does  column/rows wide mean here ?. Do you meant wide rows as too many rows in one table. Does DB's has limit for max number of rows? Similarly with column wide do you meant limitation on no of columns in a table like oracle restricts to 256 columns ?

Comment: Quest 2 `if some columns are much larger -- and rarely used -- then putting them in another table can be a big win on performance` I believe here you mean if we put it in separate table and  `select * ` will bring only relevant columns(less data read from disc and less travel on network) and better for performance ? If that's the case even if we put all columns together in a table and do select on specific columns, that's the same thing. Right ?

Comment: "Too wide" -- either a thousand columns (bad design in itself) or wide columns (documents/images/etc in `LONGTEXT`/`LONGBLOB`, etc).  To some extent, wide columns are automatically handled by InnoDB, and not a real problem.  (Caveat: this comment may be MySQL- centric.)

Comment: "big and rarely used" -- Yes, this is a valid argument for vertical partitioning.  (A big win with MyISAM, less with InnoDB.)

Comment: @emilly . . . Databases both limit the number of columns in a row and the total number of bytes in a row.  The exact limits depend on the database.

Answer (score -1):

You have many to many relationship maybe you have to create intermediate table so one for customer, one for customer_attributes and one for customer_additional_attibutes containing id of the two table

Comment: Hmmm... It sounds to me like a 1:1, not many:many.  If 1:1, then the PK of one table can be the PK of the other; no need for an intermediate table.

Comment: Yes is ok 1:1 relation because we are talking about the same thing of customer attributes, even more one table is enough I think